# How to switch between the g_printer and g_serial USB driver without rebooting the whole Linux system?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, usb, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I'm developing a project on an embedded Linux device in C, which uses those two USB drivers on the same USB cable:

- g_printer(Linux USB Printer Gadget Driver)
- g_serial(Linux Gadget Serial Driver)

When the user selects **USB Virtual COM Mode**, the program will:

1. Check whether the device file `/dev/g_printer0` is opened, if yes, close the opened file descriptor.
2. Check whether the `g_printer` is installed by using `system("lsmod | grep g_printer > /dev/null");`, if yes, use `system("rmmod g_printer);` to uninstall it.
3. Check whether the `usb_f_printer` is installed by using `system("lsmod | grep usb_f_printer > /dev/null");`, if yes, use `system("rmmod usb_f_printer);` to uninstall it.
4. Install the `g_serial` by using `system(modprobe g_serial);`
5. Open device file `/dev/ttyGS0`

When the user selects **USB Printer Mode**, the program will do almost the same steps as above, but uninstall `g_serial` first and then install `g_printer`(also the closed and opened device files are different).

But the whole Linux system crashed at step 3 when it switches from **USB Printer Mode** to **USB Virtual COM Mode**, the log shows:

```
rmmod: can't unload module 'usb_f_printer': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

In addition, this Linux kernel is customized, after the system boots, the `g_printer` is automatically installed by the kernel, but the `/dev/g_printer0` is not opened yet, so at this time, if I switch to **USB Virtual COM Mode** by using the steps above, it works with no errors(and the system won't crash of course), so it means I have another **weird** way to let the user switch between those two modes, that is when user wants to switch the mode, the system won't switch it immediately but save this selection in the configuration file, then it reboots the system, after the reboot, the program will check the configuration file to decide whether switches to **USB Virtual COM Mode** or just open `/dev/g_printer0` to be ready for use. But this is too weird :(.

I can't kill this process because this is the only process running in this device, and also I can't `exec` another process to do this USB communication stuff because it's kind of wasting memory and computing resources.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way for the user to switch those two modes without rebooting the Linux system?
2. Does it means, once a process opens the `/dev/g_printer0` device file, this driver can't be uninstalled but only reboot the system or kill the process? (even if I have already closed the opened device file)

Comment: As far as I know, the message `rmmod: can't unload module 'usb_f_printer': Resource temporarily unavailable` means that the module is somehow still in use.  Are you sure that no process has `/dev/g_printer0` open? Did you check with `lsof` and/or `fuser`? Please [edit] your question and show your code as a [mre] instead of describing what (you think) it does.

Comment: @Bodo Thanks Bodo, maybe you won't believe it, the Linux never crashes again since I add a 1s delay after the file descriptor was closed.

Comment: I can imagine that the delay will give the driver some time to clean up which will allow to remove it. A system to crash caused by trying to remove a kernel module is not normal behavior unless you have a bug in your driver. A delay might help to not trigger the bug, but that's not a proper fix. Without a [mre] we cannot help much.

Comment: You need to enable ConfigFS and libcomposite module (and of course provide all gadgets you want to have access to). Then you can configure them at run time without any recompilation.